# ordering encrypted block storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, block-storage

I'm trying to order a 250 Gb 3000 IOPS encrypted block storage.  Using request:

```
{"parameters": [{
"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
"packageId": 759,
"location": 957095,
"quantity": 1,
"iops":3000,
"prices": [ 
        { "id": 189439},
        { "id": 196039},            
        {"id": 196099}, 
        {"id":189939}],
"volumeSize": 250,
 "osFormatType":{  
        "id":24,
        "keyName":"WINDOWS_2008"
        }
}
]}
```

The error returned from verify order is:

```
{
    "error": "Undefined storage type",
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

Is there a mismatch with the items I've chosen? or with something else in the order?

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the item’s prices.

Here is an example,  how to place a block storage order by rest api.

Method: POST

https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Body: Json

{

```
"parameters": [
                {
                   "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_AsAService",
                   "location": 265592,
                   "packageId": 759,
                   "prices": [
                               {
                                 "id": 189433
                               },
                               {
                                 "id": 189443
                               },
                               {
                                 "id": 189833
                               },
                               {
                                 "id": 189893
                               }
                             ],
                   "quantity": 1,
                   "iops": 3000,
                   "osFormatType":{
                                    "id": 24,
                                    "keyName": "WINDOWS_2008"
                                  },
                   "volumeSize": 250
                 }
            ] }
```

•   This is the categoryCode and description for the item’s prices:

"id": 189433 (categoryCode: storage_as_a_service, 
           "description": "Storage as a Service")

"id": 189443 (categoryCode: storage_block, 
           "description": "Block Storage")

"id": 189833 (categoryCode: performance_storage_space, 
           “description": "100 - 499 GBs")

"id": 189893 (categoryCode: performance_storage_iops, 
           "description": "100 - 6000 IOPS")

•   You can find the ids of the item’s prices, searching in this rest api by “description” values:

Method: GET

https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/759/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,locationGroupId,item[id,keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id,name,longName]]]

e.g  "description": "Storage as a Service"

{

```
    "id": 189433,
    "locationGroupId": null,
    "item": {
        "description": "Storage as a Service",
        "id": 9571,
        "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE"
    }
}
```

e.g  “description": "100 - 499 GBs" you will find same options, but you have to choose depend of the Location that you want.

For my example I chose “Amsterdam 1” and the “id” will be "id": 189833

{

```
    "id": 189833,
    "locationGroupId": 503,
    "item": {
        "description": "100 - 499 GBs",
        "id": 9585,
        "keyName": "100_499_GBS"
    },
    "pricingLocationGroup": {
        "description": "Location Group 2",
        "id": 503,
        "locationGroupTypeId": 82,
        "name": "Location Group 2",
        "securityLevelId": null,
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": 449610,
                "longName": "Montreal 1",
                "name": "mon01"
            },
            {
                "id": 449618,
                "longName": "Montreal 2",
                "name": "mon02"
            },
            {
                "id": 448994,
                "longName": "Toronto 1",
                "name": "tor01"
            },
            {
                "id": 350993,
                "longName": "Toronto 2",
                "name": "tor02"
            },
            {
                "id": 221894,
                "longName": "Amsterdam 2",
                "name": "ams02"
            },
            {
                "id": 265592,
                "longName": "Amsterdam 1",
                "name": "ams01"
            },
            {
                "id": 814994,
                "longName": "Amsterdam 3",
                "name": "ams03"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

It is the same for the rest of the item’s prices.

Comment: Thanks,  there are items with locationGroupId = null,  are those generic available in all data centres?

Comment: Yes the price will be the same for all datacenters when the locationGroupId = null.